# Who (if anyone) could canonically tell Fred and George apart?

Tags: harry-potter, character-similarity

Is there anyone in canon who was stated to be able to tell Fred and George apart? Consistently, and not by randomly guessing.

Comment: Other than Fred and George themselves, I assume you mean. Otherwise I don't recall; presumably Dumbledore could, if he was in the habit of casually using Legilimency

Comment: Pretty sure that Ron and Harry could tell them apart. I can't recall anything from canon, though.

Comment: Clearly, not the film directors: "James and Oliver Phelps have admitted to having to reshoot some of the scenes because of them swapping roles without anyone realising"

Comment: @DVK clearly very commited to their roles

Comment: @DVK You sir, made my day. Thank you.

Comment: @DVK I don't understand why they had to reshoot scenes. Even if anyone noticed, it would be entirely in-character for Fred and George to swap places just to mess with people.

Comment: @KSmarts - You're clearly NOT a lawyer or accountant.

Comment: Actually, are there any canon scenes of anyone mixing the two up?  The closest I can recall is their introductory scene - but Molly actually addressed them properly in that one, and they only claimed otherwise for laughs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ron can tell them apart: in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* chapter 22, Ron recognizes Fred from his voice through the radio.

Harry can tell them apart at least in *Deathly Hallows*, where in chapter 31 he recognizes

> Fred before he dies in a duel,

but it might be easier at that point, because George has one of his ears hexed off by Snape.

I believe their mother Mrs. Weasley can tell them apart, see *Chamber of Secrets* chapter 3.  However, Fred and George try to deliberately confuse their mother, as seen in *Stone* chapter 6 and in *Hallows* chapter 5 when George says, after his injury:

> ‘You'll be able to tell us apart now, anyway, Mum.’

I opine J. K. Rowling could tell them apart as well.

Comment: im pretty sure angelina could tell the difference as well, since she had a thing for fred though eventually married George, yet called their child fred. according to the wiki at least haha. but fred did ask her to the yule ball.

Comment: I think Ginny could tell them apart too, but haven't got a reference for this.

Comment: One of the more magnificent but depressing Clever Theories I've heard is that it's actually was George who died in the duel, and Fred's keeping the last gag going by posing as George.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that Harry can tell them apart, as the book is told from his perspective, and he can tell who's talking during their interactions.

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you could provide some examples.

Comment: Well, the _absence_ of examples is more telling.  He never ever says "And then George - or maybe it was Fred - did such-and-so".