# What character differences between Fred and George are there?

Tags: harry-potter, character-similarity

We know that [some people](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79302/who-if-anyone-could-canonically-tell-fred-and-george-apart) could tell George and Fred apart.

Probably they weren't completely the same physically. Also, we can guess that even their characters weren't totally the same (just because they never are in the real life – even for twins).

But I don't recall any book or movie mention of some specific difference.

**What known differences between them are there?**

Note that I am only interested in character differences (i.e. personality) not physical appearance.

Also note, that primarily I am curious about books or Pottermore references and I do not care that much about the movies. But if nothing else is available, movies are acceptable as well.

Comment: [Five](https://planetcalc.com/1721/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The slight variation in their personality according to J.K. Rowling is,

> Fred was the ringleader, George the “gentler” twin.
>
> Fred is normally the funnier but also the crueler of the two. So they might have thought that George would be the more vulnerable one and, therefore, the one to die.”
>
> She didn’t make her decision because it was easier to kill one twin over the other, however.
>
> "[Rowling: I wanted to kill parents", July 29, 2007, Interview by Jen Brown](https://www.today.com/popculture/rowling-i-wanted-kill-parents-2d80555846)

Answer (score -1):

## Fred is dead, George isn't dead

This is the most stark difference in their personalities. Other differences include:

1. Fred is more sarcastic and daring
2. George is more gentle and moral, his humor is more self-deprecating
3. Fred is better at non-verbal magic
4. George is quieter, but this is only compared to his brother.

Comment: The answer would benefit from some source / book quotation to support these points.

Comment: Do you have instances from the book (or movie if unavailable) to back any of those points up?

Comment: Death doesn't seem to be a personality trait.... so I am not sure why you lead with that...

Comment: @Skooba-Stands-Against-AI A dead person scores very low on several personality traits such as: Conscientiousness, Extraversion, Self Awareness, Competence, Mindful, etc. And very high on other traits such as: Apathy, Patience, Laziness, Rigidness, Thoughtlessness, and Forgetfulness.

Comment: It’s interesting you say that Fred **is** dead when he isn’t for most of the story. After all, if you call someone a “Scrooge”, you don’t mean they are a kindly boss who brings a fat goose to their employee’s Christmas dinner.

Comment: @BenMurphy The key here is in the tense of the verb used in the question "What known differences between them are there?" if it said "were" instead of "are" then the dead aspect would be incorrect. When you call someone a "Scrooge" that's shorthand for saying he's like Scrooge was before he reformed, and if you wanted to say someone is a "Reformed Scrooge" it would imply his state at the end of the story.